# How can you prevent multiple instances of RDP from opening using Process.Start?

Tags: c#, winforms, process, rdp, process.start

I am simply trying to open the Windows RDP application through a button click event in my C# application, but what I get is 4 or 5 instances of RDP on a single click. I was wondering if this is a result of having the code in a button click event. I've researched Mutex, but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for in this particular case. Any ideas?

```
private void btnRemote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string rdcSupport = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\mstsc.exe";

    try
    {
        procRDC.StartInfo.FileName = rdcSupport;
        procRDC.Start();
        procRDC.WaitForInputIdle();
        SendKeys.Send("support_server1");
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to open...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Place a breakpoint in the click handler. How many times does it run per click?

Comment: According to HandleCount, it opens between 3 and 5 randomly.

Comment: I didn't ask about `HandleCount`. I asked, specifically, how many times the click handler executes for each click. You can establish this easily by placing a breakpoint on the first line of the handler method, or alternatively, you could place the following as the first line `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("I was clicked");` and seeing how many times it appears in the debug output.

Comment: It seems strange that you are using SendKeys to do something supported by the [command line parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753907(v=ws.11).aspx) of mstsc.exe

Comment: Getting warmer. So, the problem is not in the code that you have presented. It's because you are attaching more that one event listener to the click event causing the handling method to be executed more than once for every click. How many times are you adding a handler to the click event? Now you need to place a breakpoint at the `btnRemote.Click+=...` line to see how many times it runs.

Comment: Really thought I was about to stumble across some duplicate code and say that this question is now closed, but it looks like there is only one handler for that particular button and it only fires once if I'm viewing it correctly. But how is that the case if it technically fires twice each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be SendKeys doing some mess. I would recomend using MSTSC parameters:

```
try
{
    Process procRDC = Process.Start(rdcSupport, "/v:support_server1");
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to open...");
}
```

You don't show how you create/initialize procRDP.

See MSTSC help: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753907(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: This was it. But why? As soon as I changed it from the SendKeys to the mstsc parameters, the duplicate processes stop happening. It now works exactly as intended with one process starting after a single button click...

Comment: SendKey sending keys to active application, but there is no guarante that MSTCS will be active application after starting it. It should, but... May the ENTER key pressed your button again. It is hard to say.

Comment: Perhaps the `{ENTER}` was being sent to the button, triggering it again?

Comment: Those both sound like valid reasons to me... Thanks to both of you for the help!